# Criar um URL para abrir um arquivo PDF - PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde a todos,

Estou desenvolvendo um código para busca de palavras-chave nos dados do banco. Até aí, ok! Porém, estou patinando ao tentar abrir o arquivo referente ao resultado que achei.

Esse é o código para busca da palavra-chave:

```
<?php

// Include conexão com o bd.
include 'conexaoBD/conexao.php';
include 'teste.php';


$btn     = $_POST['btn'];
$p_chave = $_POST['palavra'];

if(isset($btn)){
    $busca = $p_chave;

    if($busca == null or $busca == " "){

        echo '<center><b>Digite a palavra-chave para pesquisar!</b></center>';

    } else {

        $busca_div = explode(' ',$busca);
        $quant     = count($busca_div);
        $exibe_id  = array("");

        for($i=0; $i<$quant; $i++){
            $pesquisa = $busca_div[$i];

            $_sql       = "SELECT * FROM conteudo_dcm WHERE DCM_conteudo LIKE '%$pesquisa%';";
            $sql        = mysqli_query($conn,$_sql);

            $quant_cmps = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

            if($quant_cmps == 0){

                echo '<center><b>Nenhum resultado obtido!</b></center>';

            } else {

                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $id       = $linha['DCM_id'];
                    $nome     = $linha['DCM_nome'];
                    $conteudo = $linha['DCM_conteudo'];

                    $_href = $_folder.$_DS.$nome; // Variável definida no arquivo "teste.php"

                    if(!array_search($id,$exibe_id)){
                        echo '<a href="<?php $_href; ?>">'.$nome.'</a>'."<br><br>".
                             substr($conteudo, 0, 600)."<b> ...</b>".
                             "<br>---------------------<br>";   

                        array_push($exibe_id,$id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Minha dúvida está principalmente nesta parte do código (como montar a url refente ao arquivo que salvei no servidor).

```
echo '<a href="<?php $_href; ?>">'.$nome.'</a>'."<br><br>".
                                 substr($conteudo, 0, 600)."<b> ...</b>".
                                 "<br>---------------------<br>";
```

Comment: Eu estou chutando que a sua variável `$folder` está preenchida com o diretório dentro do sistema operacional onde você grava os arquivos, é isso mesmo? Se for o caso você tem que traduzir este caminho para a rota que leva até o arquivo entrando pelo http. Se puder colocar o trecho que cria esta variável eu posso tentar ajudar mais.

Comment: Sim @DiegoMartins, a variável $folder é o diretório onde os arq. estão armazenados. Segue o trecho que cria essa variável: " $_DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$_folder = dirname(__DIR__).$_DS.'03-OCR-PDFlib'.$_DS.'arqs_Teste'; "

Answer (score 1):

Quando um arquivo PDF for aberto em um navegador, a primeira página do arquivo PDF será mostrada por padrão. Você pode adicionar uma sequência de caracteres no link HTML para que um arquivo PDF seja aberto e pule para uma página especificada ou defina o destino. Para usar um desses dois métodos, faça o seguinte:

Abrir um arquivo PDF em uma página específica
Para direcionar um link HTML em uma página em um arquivo PDF específico, adicione #page= [número da página] no final do URL do link.

Por exemplo, esse tag HTML abre a página 4 de um arquivo PDF denominado myfile.pdf:

Observação: se você usar locais do servidor UNC (\ nome_do_servidor\ pasta) em um link, defina o link para abrir um destino definido usando o procedimento na próxima seção. Se você usa URLs contendo endereços locais do disco rígido (c:\pasta), não é possível vincular aos números de página ou aos destinos definidos. Com produtos Adobe Acrobat 7.0, um link para um número de página somente funciona se você usar locais HTTP ou HTTPS. Os locais do servidor UNC somente funcionarão se você usar o método destinos definidos descrito na próxima seção deste documento.